# how to search a file from multiple path and paste it in other locations using batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

I need to search a file from two paths either program files or program files x86 and copy the file and paste it in some other location.

Now I have used the script as

```
@echo off
xcopy C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Adobe\"Adobe Presenter 10.0"\"Gallery"\"interactions"\"Collaboration" %~dp0 /e /h /k /o /y
Echo Files copied!
pause
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix your quotes. There should only be quotes at the beginning and end of each path. Like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Presenter 10.0\Gallery\interactions\Collaboration"
```

You may also want to put quotes around:

```
"%~dp0"
```

in case the path has spaces in it.

I'd probably just make a quick, simple script like:

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Presenter 10.0\Gallery\interactions\Collaboration" (
    xcopy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Presenter 10.0\Gallery\interactions\Collaboration" "%~dp0" /e /h /k /o /y
    echo copied from Program Files (x86)
)
if exist "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Presenter 10.0\Gallery\interactions\Collaboration" (
    xcopy "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Presenter 10.0\Gallery\interactions\Collaboration" "%~dp0" /e /h /k /o /y
    echo copied from Program Files
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
rem Define an environment variable with folder name for easier reading and changing in future.
set "MyFolder=Adobe\Adobe Presenter 10.0\Gallery\interactions\Collaboration"
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\%MyFolder%" (
   xcopy "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\%MyFolder%" "%~dp0" /e /h /k /o /y
   echo Files copied!
) else (
   if exist "%ProgramFiles%\%MyFolder%" (
      xcopy "%ProgramFiles%\%MyFolder%" "%~dp0" /e /h /k /o /y
      echo Files copied!
   )
)
rem Not really necessary here, but good practice is to delete finally the temporary used environment variable.
set MyFolder=
```

For details about command `IF` open a command prompt window an enter `IF /?` to get displayed help about this command.

The enviroment variable `ProgramFiles(x86)` is by default set in all 64-bit Windows, but does not exist on 32-bit Windows.

The enviroment variable `ProgramFiles` exists for 32- and 64-bit Windows.

Double quotes must be just used (usually) at beginning and end of a parameter string and the file name of an application with full path containing a space character. The full path to the folder is a parameter. There is no need to use inside a file/path string also double quotes. Some applications could parse them wrong.